# how to view final url before submission curl php

Tags: php, curl

I want to know final url just before executing curl to check all parameters passing as desired. how to view that.

```
<?PHP
function openurl($url) {
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postvars);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, '3');
    $content = trim(curl_exec($ch));  
    curl_close($ch); 
    echo $content;
}
$postvars = array('user' => "user123",'password' => "user@user!123",'Text' => "Test");
$sms_url ="http://remoteserver/plain";
openurl($sms_url);
?>

desired output to check all params and its values passing correct..
http://remoteserver/plain?user=user123&password=user@user!123&Text=TESThere
```

Comment: Erm, you are not doing anything with that array... You just set it.

Comment: In you example, $sms_url is just the domain, you didn't add the params ($postvars). If you want to *check* the url, first make it complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add the `$postvars` as parameter to your function.

```
function openurl($url, $postvars) {
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postvars);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, '3');
    $content = trim(curl_exec($ch));  
    curl_close($ch); 
    echo $content;
}

$postvars = array('user' => "user123",'password' => "user@user!123",'Text' => "Test");
$sms_url ="http://remoteserver/plain";

// create a test var which we can display on screen / log
$test_url = sms_url . http_build_query($postvars);

// either send it to the browser
echo $test_url;

// or send it to your log (make sure loggin is enabled!)
error_log("CURL URL: $test_url", 0);

openurl($sms_url, $postvars);
```

Comment: Thanks, Roger! this is the nearest possible solution I have .but observed sometimes http_build_query() not working as desired.